# Populate a jlist from text file read through button

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist, jfilechooser

[image]

Code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
//fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new     File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 

{
File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
DefaultListModel lista = new DefaultListModel();
JList jList1 = new JList();

try {
        FileReader archivo = new     FileReader(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        BufferedReader lector = new BufferedReader(archivo);
        String texto = null;
        while ((texto = lector.readLine()) != null) {
            lista.addElement(texto);
            //System.out.println("Lista:"+lista);
            //System.out.println(texto);
        }

        jList1.setModel(lista);
        System.out.println("jList1:"+jList1);

    } 

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}    

}
```

I am trying to Populate a jlist from text file read through Read_file button

I am able to fetch the file path and the contents of the file correctly which I validated with a print statement, but still my jlist remains empty.
In the design, I checked the variable name of the  jlist, both matches what I have used in the code.

Please suggest me on the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i see you create a new `JList` each time you hit the button. You do properly fill the `DefaultListModel` but you assigned to some jList not to the one you have on your UI.

Just clear the line :

```
JList jList1 = new JList();
```

then `repaint` and `revalidate` it's container after `setModel`

Comment: In other words, you may fill the the jList1 but it is a local variable which you never put back on the `JPanel`.. The list is ok, you dont show it. The best case is to have a Jlist object on your UI and each time you hit the button you update its model. No need to remove the entire list.

Comment: You have literally done everything right but you do not  present it. You create a JList1, you fill it, but you dont put in ON the UI.  Step1: add a jlist on your UI and answer me what you called it.

Comment: i named it jList1, and that is why I have used the same name in the code

Comment: you added just like the textearea and the button? are you able to see it? i dont see it on your screenshot

Comment: @gvlachkis the white box in the image is not a text area, it is a jlist.

Comment: Perfect, then from your code clear the line : JList jList1 = new JList();

Comment: does the listmodel fills properly? Does it have entries? if yes, try to revalidate your UI. Call revalidate and repaint after jList1.setModel(lista);

Comment: The problem is that by creating a new list there you were filling the new list, and not the one displayed on your ui. goodluck, thx for accepting.

Comment: just one more thing, what  do you mean by repaint and revalidate after set model?

Comment: Since it worked without it you do not need it, but sometimes it is possible mostly when you paint on a JFrame the changes are not displayed immediately, you need to call repaint to see them. Similarly there is revalidate for adding/removing components, it is quite common to use them together.